# Jquery animation and when function

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

When I use my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("it started");
    swapsies();
});

function swapsies() {

    $('.lang').on('click', function(){
        console.log("here");
        //.when(

        $.when(
          $(this).animate({ "margin-left": "-=10" }, 500),
          $('.active').animate({ "margin-left": "+=10" }, 500)
        ).done(function(){
            console.log("done");
        });
    });    
}
```

Both elements, this and active supposed to move and switch places, but only active element is moving! I dont know, maybe it is because of the wait function
Here is my html so you could run this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" ></script>
    <title>Test swapsies</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fied">
        <button type="button" id="bb">Click Me!</button>
        <div id="swapthis">
            <ul>
                <li class="active lang"><a href="#">En</a></li>
                <li class="lang"><a href="#">Fr</a></li>
                <li class="lang"><a href="#">Es</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And css:

```
li{
    display:inline;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.active{
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
}
```

Please help me figure out how to make both elements to move - the one that was clicked on and the one that uses .active class.

Comment: Made a fiddle out of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/dambmp68/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should make the element you click moving more left.
instead of "-=10"

```
$(this).animate({ "margin-left": "-=10" }, 500)
```

using "-=20"

```
$(this).animate({ "margin-left": "-=20" }, 500)
```

I've test your code on jsfiddle.
The fact the element you click is not moving showing exactly the code is working.

Since you're asking the element on its left moving right 10 px (which makes itself moves right 10px) and then asking the element moving left 10 px, makes it not moving at all.

but since you might not want the element on its right moves too, you should also handling those elements' margin

I've modify your code like this:

```
$('.lang').on('click', function(){
    var dist = 10;
    console.log("here");
    //.when(
    $.when(
      $(this).animate({ "margin-left": "-="+dist*2 }, 500),
      $(this).next().animate({ "margin-left": "+="+dist }, 500),
      $('.active').animate({ "margin-left": "+="+dist }, 500)
    ).done(function(){
        console.log("done");
    });

});
```

increasing dist if you want to move more.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("it started");
    swapsies();
});

function swapsies() {
    $(".lang").on("click", function(e) {
        $(e.target)
        .parent()
        .siblings()
        .removeClass("active")
        .animate({"left":"0"}, -500)
        .end()
        .addClass("active")
        .animate({"margin-left": "-=10", "left":"0px"}, 500, function() {
            $(this).prependTo($(this).parent())
            .animate({"margin-left": "+=10", "left":"-=10"}, 500, function() {
              $(this).siblings().animate({"left": "0"}, 500)
              .promise().then(function() {
                console.log("done")
              })
            })
        });
    });
}
```

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: calc(0%);
  margin-left: calc(0%);
  margin-right: calc(0%);
  width: calc(1%);
}
.active {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  left:-10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="fied">
  <button type="button" id="bb">Click Me!</button>
  <div id="swapthis">
    <ul>
      <li class="active lang"><a href="#">En</a>
      </li>
      <li class="lang"><a href="#">Fr</a>
      </li>
      <li class="lang"><a href="#">Es</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: works waaay better than mine, but still dont really finish the animation. i need the active element to go left:/